# ASP.NET authentication: adding similar part (domain) to all usernames

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am working on an authentication process for an ASP.NET web app. All my usernames follow the same template: *login@domain.com*. Domain is always the same.

My question is: Is there a way to add the part *@domain.com* automatically, so users could just type in their *login* in the username field?

Please, let me know if I need to provide some additional info to find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add domain name programmatically if it's not specified by users:

```
//var userNameWithDomain = "abc@domain.com" or "abc"; //get it from user's
//input
string[] arrUserName = userNameWithDomain.Split("@".ToCharArray());
string userName = null;
string domainName = null;

if (arrUserName.Length > 1)
{
     userName = arrUserName[0];
     domainName = arrUserName[1];
}
else
{
     userName = userNameWithDomain;
     domainName = "domain.com";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still working on incorporating it into my code, but I got the main idea. Thank you again :)